# Better way of doing it - GetFiles - c#

Tags: c#, path, getfiles

I'm trying to get all files in a directory but I want them associated with numbers. Now, I have this:

```
string[] ficheiro = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\David\Documents\Jogos\Jogos de emuladores\Roms GB\", "*.gba");
{
     Console.WriteLine ("F1" + " - " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension (ficheiro[0]));
}
Console.ReadKey ();
```

When I reach 10 files I will have a shortcut to flip a page to get more files (10 per page). I will list all files by hand. Like this:

```
Console.WriteLine ("F2" + " - " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension (ficheiro[1]));

Console.WriteLine ("F3" + " - " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension (ficheiro[2]));
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: This question seems like a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, as you don't seem to have a problem.  You want to improve the quality of your code.

Comment: Actually I think that I'm doing it wrong. Because I will have to do all pages by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a loop. You cannot do all of them "by hand" because you do not necessarily know how many there are.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Your\Directory\Path", "*.gba");
var count = 0;

foreach (var file in files)
{
    if (count % 10 == 0 && count != 0)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    count++;

    Console.WriteLine("F{0} - {1}", count, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Ok, it's pretty good. But it skips the first and second file. And how do I will add pages to that? Can you explain that to me? I'm pretty nub on this. Thanks for the time.

Comment: Actually it isn't skipping any file, its just printing the wrong number. I have updated it to fix this issue.

Comment: That's great. Now, how I make some sort of pages, like this: I click on a key and the command prompt clean that first 10 files and gives me the other files that i have? like a page?

Comment: you could try to use Console.Clear(). Here is the documentation from the msdn page.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.clear(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, that will be usefull. But how do I go on with the files? Like the 11, 12, 13, 14 to 20 be displayed in the command prompt? And after clicking again it show the 21, 22, 23, 24 to 30? That's my main question.

Comment: maybe i dont understand your question, but if you hit the enter key after it prints the first ten files, it should print out the next 10 files (11-20), then if you hit enter again, it should print the next 10 (21-30)

Comment: Sorry kmc, but I have a question now. If I want another key to display the other page like F12? How can i do it?

Comment: You can use Console.Read() which returns an integer for which key was pressed each time the user presses a key. 

````while(Console.Read() != 123) {}````

where 123 came from is the F12 character code. Found here: http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/re-ascii-code-for-functions-keys-f1-f12-and-tab-key.277457/

Comment: But where can I put it?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the array with a for-loop :

```
string[] ficheiros = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\David\Documents\Jogos\Jogos de emuladores\Roms GB\", "*.gba");
for (int i = 0; i < ficheiros.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("F{0} - {1}", i + 1, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ficheiros[i]));
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

The key is to identify the repeating part and extract a pattern from it :

```
//only these changed V                                                       V
Console.WriteLine ("F2" + " - " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension (ficheiro[1]));
Console.WriteLine ("F3" + " - " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension (ficheiro[2]));

// just replace them and put it inside an appropriate loop, in this case a for-loop
for(int i = 0; i < ficheiro.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine ("F" + (i+1) + " - " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension (ficheiro[i]));
```

Comment: It gives me the same file 12 times (the number of files that I have in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int i = 0;
        var ficheiro = from s in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\", "*.*")
                       select ("F"+ i++  + "-" + s);
```